# Multiprocessing limit threads used

Tags: python-2.7

I have some large lists containing data, that needs processing. I'm using multiprocessing to get the job done faster and it works great unless the lists contain more than 100 lines, since it then starts to use a lot of CPU and Memory.

I have provided some sample data:

```
changed_devices = [[3036c360, 013-HX.ITEM-UA-01, DESCRIPTION 6, 172.29.6.2, Location#All Locations#013-LOCATION-1, IPSEC#Is IPSEC Device#No, Device Type#All Device Types#Switch, ISE Config#ISE Config#With ISE Config Monitor Mode, ISE_enable#ISE_enable#YES - Monitor Mode],
[306fd4c0, 013-HX.ITEM-UA-02, DESCRIPTION 7, 172.29.6.3, Location#All Locations#013-LOCATION-1, IPSEC#Is IPSEC Device#No, Device Type#All Device Types#Switch, ISE Config#ISE Config#With ISE Config Monitor Mode, ISE_enable#ISE_enable#YES - Monitor Mode],
[30a8bf10, 013-UX.ITEM-UA-01, DESCRIPTION 8, 172.29.6.10, Location#All Locations#013-LOCATION-1, IPSEC#Is IPSEC Device#No, Device Type#All Device Types#Switch, ISE Config#ISE Config#With ISE Config Monitor Mode, ISE_enable#ISE_enable#YES - Monitor Mode],
[30e293c0, 013-UX1.ITEM-UA-01, DESCRIPTION 1, 172.29.6.4, Location#All Locations#013-LOCATION-1, IPSEC#Is IPSEC Device#No, Device Type#All Device Types#Switch, ISE Config#ISE Config#With ISE Config Monitor Mode, ISE_enable#ISE_enable#YES - Monitor Mode],
[311cb690, 013-UX2.ITEM-UA-01, DESCRIPTION 2, 172.29.6.5, Location#All Locations#013-LOCATION-1, IPSEC#Is IPSEC Device#No, Device Type#All Device Types#Switch, ISE Config#ISE Config#With ISE Config Monitor Mode, ISE_enable#ISE_enable#YES - Monitor Mode],
[3155ef00, 013-UX3.ITEM-UA-01, DESCRIPTION 3, 172.29.6.6, Location#All Locations#013-LOCATION-1, IPSEC#Is IPSEC Device#No, Device Type#All Device Types#Switch, ISE Config#ISE Config#With ISE Config Monitor Mode, ISE_enable#ISE_enable#YES - Monitor Mode],
[318ed950, 013-UX4.ITEM-UA-01, DESCRIPTION 4, 172.29.6.7, Location#All Locations#013-LOCATION-1, IPSEC#Is IPSEC Device#No, Device Type#All Device Types#Switch, ISE Config#ISE Config#With ISE Config Monitor Mode, ISE_enable#ISE_enable#YES - Monitor Mode],
[31c8d510, 013-UX5.ITEM-UA-01, DESCRIPTION 5, 172.29.6.8, Location#All Locations#013-LOCATION-1, IPSEC#Is IPSEC Device#No, Device Type#All Device Types#Switch, ISE Config#ISE Config#With ISE Config Monitor Mode, ISE_enable#ISE_enable#YES - Monitor Mode],
[3202f7e0, 013-UX5.ITEM-UA-02, DESCRIPTION 5, 172.29.6.9, Location#All Locations#013-LOCATION-1, IPSEC#Is IPSEC Device#No, Device Type#All Device Types#Switch, ISE Config#ISE Config#With ISE Config Monitor Mode, ISE_enable#ISE_enable#YES - Monitor Mode]]
```

My current code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for chg in range(len(changed_devices)):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=start_exscript, args=(accounts,changed_devices[chg][0],changed_devices[chg][1],changed_devices[chg][2],changed_devices[chg][3],changed_devices[chg][4],changed_devices[chg][5],changed_devices[chg][6],changed_devices[chg][7],changed_devices[chg][8],changed_devices[chg][9],changed_devices[chg][10],))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

The lists can contain more than 5000 entries, so i would like the script to account for this and only start like 100 threads at a time. Anyone have an idea?

**UPDATE:**

I still cannot get this to work, so i'll supply some extra details.

I'm using Python 2.7 and i couldn't get `concurrent.futures` to work.

The `start_exscript` is just another function, it looks like this:

```
def start_exscript(accounts, host, ena, ise_nwdvs_id, ise_nwdvs_name, ise_nwdvs_ip, ise_nwdvs_desc, ise_nwdvs_loc, ise_nwdvs_ipsec, ise_nwdvs_type, ise_nwdvs_cfg, ise_nwdvs_ena):
    try:
        start(accounts, host, bind(update_config_cisco_device, ena), verbose=0) # starts Python Exscript
        updateisedvsdata = [ise_nwdvs_id, ise_nwdvs_name, ise_nwdvs_ip,  ise_nwdvs_desc, ise_nwdvs_loc, ise_nwdvs_ipsec, ise_nwdvs_type, ise_nwdvs_cfg, ise_nwdvs_ena]
        ise_update_nw_dvs = ise_update_network_device(updateisedvsdata) # Start update function
        if ise_update_nw_dvs:
            logger.critical("[ROOT]: Updating ISE config variable on: [ "+ise_nwdvs_name+" ] [ OK ]")
        else:
            logger.critical("[ROOT]: Updating ISE config variable on: [ "+ise_nwdvs_name+" ] [ Failed ]")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.critical(e.message, e.args)
```

[Python Exscript](https://exscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) is just an add on which can login to network devices.

I'm having trouble passing all the arguments i have using Pool.

I tried this, but it wont start:

```
cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1
pool = Pool(processes=cpus)

for chg in range(len(changed_devices)):
    pool.apply_async(start_exscript,args=(accounts,changed_devices[chg][0],changed_devices[chg][1],changed_devices[chg][2],changed_devices[chg][3],changed_devices[chg][4],changed_devices[chg][5],changed_devices[chg][6],changed_devices[chg][7],changed_devices[chg][8],changed_devices[chg][9],changed_devices[chg][10]))

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Nothing happens with this. I dont even get an error, which confuses me more.

**UPDATE 2**

Final working result for anyone looking out there. Thanks a lot to SyntaxVoid.

```
def start_exscript(args):
    try:
        # --- PLEASE READ ---
        # Setup Switch/Router CLI access - remember to change
        cliuser = "x"
        clipass = "x"
        accounts = Account(cliuser,clipass,needs_lock=False)

        host = args[0]
        ena = args[1]
        ise_nwdvs_id = args[2]
        ise_nwdvs_name = args[3]
        ise_nwdvs_ip = args[4]
        ise_nwdvs_desc = args[5]
        ise_nwdvs_loc = args[6]
        ise_nwdvs_ipsec = args[7]
        ise_nwdvs_type = args[8]
        ise_nwdvs_cfg = args[9]
        ise_nwdvs_ena = args[10]

        start(accounts, host, bind(update_config_cisco_device, ena), verbose=0) # Start Exscript process
        updateisedvsdata = [ise_nwdvs_id, ise_nwdvs_name, ise_nwdvs_ip,  ise_nwdvs_desc, ise_nwdvs_loc, ise_nwdvs_ipsec, ise_nwdvs_type, ise_nwdvs_cfg, ise_nwdvs_ena] # Update data
        ise_update_nw_dvs = ise_update_network_device(updateisedvsdata) # Start update process
        if ise_update_nw_dvs: # If update went well
            logger.critical("[ROOT]: Updating ISE config variable on: [ "+ise_nwdvs_name+" ] [ OK ]")
        else:
            logger.critical("[ROOT]: Updating ISE config variable on: [ "+ise_nwdvs_name+" ] [ Failed ]")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.critical(e.message, e.args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1
    pool = Pool(processes=cpus)
    results = pool.map(start_exscript, changed_devices)
```

Comment: You may want to implement a pool of 100 processes that pull arguments from a queue whenever they have a chance. That way, there is only ever a max of 100 processes running.

Comment: @SyntaxVoid sounds like a good plan, how do i go about it? Could you provide me with an example?

Comment: Still unanswered i hope someone could shed a light over this. Please see updated section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example using the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) module.

**Edit: Originally this manually handled the queues but as Roland pointed out, `Pool` is already designed to do this for you.**

In the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block, we create the Pool with the maximum number of processes we want to allow and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) it to our list of input arguments. For this example, it will calculate the square of 0 through 24. Because of how `map` works, the order of `results` will match up with the order of your input arguments, even though they may finish executing out of order. The random processing time in the worker function helps demonstrate that.

Code:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os
import time
import random

def worker(x):
    pid = os.getpid()
    print(f"PID: {pid} got {x}. Evaluating now...")
    processing_time = random.uniform(0.2, 5)
    time.sleep(processing_time)    
    output = x**2
    print(f"PID: {pid} done evaluating in {processing_time:.2f}s. {x}**2 = {output}.")
    return output


if __name__ == "__main__":
    max_processes = 5
    with Pool(max_processes) as pool:
        results = pool.map(worker, range(25))
    print(results)
```

**EDIT**:

To help apply this to your code, take a look at the [`pool.map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map) documentation.

> **map(func, iterable[, chunksize])**
>
> A parallel equivalent of the map() built-in function (it supports only one iterable argument though). It blocks until the result is ready.
>
> This method chops the iterable into a number of chunks which it submits to the process pool as separate tasks. The (approximate) size of these chunks can be specified by setting chunksize to a positive integer.

Each element of the iterable you pass should be the set of arguments you want for each function call. Unfortunately, I don't think you'll be able to use keyword arguments for your `start_exscript` function since you are only able to pass a single object. There are several ways around this but I think this is the most straight foward:

1. Redefine your `start_exscript` function like this:

```py
def start_exscript(args):
    accounts, host, ena, ise_nwdvs_id, ise_nwdvs_name, ise_nwdvs_ip,
    ise_nwdvs_desc, ise_nwdvs_loc, ise_nwdvs_ipsec, ise_nwdvs_type,
    ise_nwdvs_cfg, ise_nwdvs_ena = args
    # The rest of your function can stay the same
```

If you do this, then the object you use as your iterable to pass to map should look like a list of lists where each inner list is the arguments to pass to `start_exscript`. Like:

```
pass_this_to_map = [ [ARGUMENTS_FOR_FIRST_CALL], [ARGUMENTS_FOR_SECOND_CALL], ... ]
```

If I'm understanding your code correctly, I think all you have to do is pass your `changed_devices` list to map: `pool.map(start_exscript, changed_devices)` after re-definding your function like I did above.

**If you don't have access to the source code of `start_exscript` (as in, you can't change it) then you have to write a wrapper like this**:

```py
def start_exscript_wrapper(f):
    def inner(args):
        return f(*args)
    return inner
```

And then do

```py
start_exscript = start_exscript_wrapper(start_exscript)
```

before you call it.

Comment: The whole point of using a `Pool` is that it takes care of supplying the workers with data and returning results without you having to do that yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, looks like something i could use. Will work with it and see if i can find a solution using the Pool.

Comment: I have tried your example, but i cannot fathom how it would translate to the code i used. I cant seem to parse all those arguments combined with the fact, that it just doesn't seem to start. Please see updated code.

Comment: Well, you sir, are a Python guru! Thank you so much for giving the extra details. You were absolutely right, that i could just parse the list directly. Only had to move a few things around. Will update the result to my question later today. Again, thanks man.

Answer (score 2):

What you should do in such a case is use a limited number of processes and let them take care of all the items in the list.

Luckily, Python has you covered in this case.

Basically, there are three solutions:

- `multiprocessing.Pool`
- `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`
- `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`

The name of your current worker function, `start_exscript`, kind of implies that you are using e.g. `subprocess` to start an external program.

If that is correct, I would suggest using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`. Here is one of my programs as a complete working example. It uses `ffmpeg` to do a batch conversion of video's to MKV format:

```
from functools import partial
import argparse
import concurrent.futures as cf
import logging
import os
import subprocess as sp
import sys

__version__ = '1.4.1'


def main(argv):
    """
    Entry point for vid2mkv.

    Arguments:
        argv: Command line arguments.
    """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
    parser.add_argument(
        '-q', '--videoquality', type=int, default=6, help='video quality (0-10, default 6)'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '-a', '--audioquality', type=int, default=3, help='audio quality (0-10, default 3)'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--log',
        default='warning',
        choices=['debug', 'info', 'warning', 'error'],
        help="logging level (defaults to 'warning')"
    )
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', action='version', version=__version__)
    parser.add_argument("files", metavar='file', nargs='+', help="one or more files to process")
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=getattr(logging, args.log.upper(), None), format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s'
    )
    logging.debug(f'command line arguments = {args}')
    logging.debug(f'parsed arguments = {args}')
    # Check for required programs.
    try:
        sp.run(['ffmpeg'], stdout=sp.DEVNULL, stderr=sp.DEVNULL)
        logging.debug('found “ffmpeg”')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        logging.error('the “ffmpeg” program cannot be found')
        sys.exit(1)
    # Work starts here.
    starter = partial(runencoder, vq=args.videoquality, aq=args.audioquality)
    with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as tp:
        fl = [tp.submit(starter, t) for t in args.files]
        for fut in cf.as_completed(fl):
            fn, rv = fut.result()
            if rv == 0:
                logging.info(f'finished "{fn}"')
            elif rv < 0:
                logging.warning(f'file "{fn}" has unknown extension, ignoring it.')
            else:
                logging.error(f'conversion of "{fn}" failed, return code {rv}')


def runencoder(fname, vq, aq):
    """
    Convert a video file to Theora/Vorbis streams in a Matroska container.

    Arguments:
        fname: Name of the file to convert.
        vq : Video quality. See ffmpeg docs.
        aq: Audio quality. See ffmpeg docs.

    Returns:
        (fname, return value)
    """
    basename, ext = os.path.splitext(fname)
    known = [
        '.mp4', '.avi', '.wmv', '.flv', '.mpg', '.mpeg', '.mov', '.ogv', '.mkv', '.webm', '.gif'
    ]
    if ext.lower() not in known:
        return (fname, -1)
    ofn = basename + '.mkv'
    args = [
        'ffmpeg', '-i', fname, '-c:v', 'libtheora', '-q:v',
        str(vq), '-c:a', 'libvorbis', '-q:a',
        str(aq), '-sn', '-y', ofn
    ]
    logging.debug(' '.join(args))
    logging.info(f'starting conversion of "{fname}".')
    cp = sp.run(args, stdout=sp.DEVNULL, stderr=sp.DEVNULL)
    return fname, cp.returncode


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Of note:

- I'm using `functools.partial` to pre-supply arguments that do not change between calls to `runencoder`.
- Since some conversions may take longer than others, I use `as_completed` on a list of `Futures`. This will yield results as soon as they become available.
- I'm returning both the name of the file and the result, because the order wherein results appear are probably not the order they were submitted.
- When you are running `multiprocessing.Pool` or `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` or running a number of subprocesses by hand, it usually *makes no sense* to start more processes than your CPU has cores. As you have discovered, you get lots of processes fighting over CPU resources.

If all encoder runs take approximately the same time, I could have used the `map` method of the `Executor`, which is slightly simpler. And that would return results in the order they were submitted.

*If* you are **not** using `subprocess` in the worker function, but are doing the actual work in Python, simple change `ThreadPoolExecutor` to `ProcessPoolExecutor` and you'd be fine.

**Edit**: Since you are on 2.7, a [backport](https://pypi.org/project/futures/) of concurrent.futures is available for 2.7.
But in your use-case, `multiprocessing.Pool` should work OK.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this. It's definitely an eye opener, but since i have limited experience i might not understand all of it, but i'll take the time to try and test it out. For now i'll go with the Pool option as explained by SyntaxVoid.

Comment: After a lot of headache i found out that your code only works with Python 3 and i'm using Python 2.7. start_exscript is just another function. Please see my updated code. I hope you will spend a little time looking it over.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. These days I assume that Python == Python 3, since 2.7 will be EOL in january 2020. You might want to consider adding the python 2.7 tag next time.

Comment: You are right or all together upgrade to Python 3. Sorry i forgot to tag correctly.